# Why i get strange errors in console when AngularJS module loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use Angularjs 1.2.21 in my project.

I download and install angular-route.min.js file

Here is main module defenition:

```
angular.module('dashboard', ['ngRoute','layers'])
.config(function () {});
```

In console I get this 2 errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of null
    at initialize.setMap (OpenLayers.js:625)
    at initialize.addLayer (OpenLayers.js:182)
    at initialize.addLayers (OpenLayers.js:182)
    at initialize (OpenLayers.js:177)
    at mapApp.js:205
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mapApp.js:221)
    at fire (jquery-1.8.3.js:974)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.3.js:1084)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.8.3.js:406)
    at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery-1.8.3.js:83)
```

And second error is this:

```
angular.min.js:92 TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
    at Tb.$$parse (angular.min.js:86)
    at angular.min.js:90
    at k.$eval (angular.min.js:111)
    at k.$digest (angular.min.js:108)
    at angular.min.js:90
    at angular.min.js:38
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:38)
    at angular.min.js:31
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
```

When I remove ngRoute from dependency injection everything works fine:

```
angular.module('dashboard', ['layers'])
.config(function () {});
```

Any idea why I get errors above?

Comment: You should not use the minified version for development.